how to use oModel.create() method in SAPUI5
I have this method in my controller in Business Applications Studio SAPUI5 but it doesn't work as expected.
I want the file to be attached to the invoice with the provided Objectkey which works perfectly fine with the second function, but when executing the first function, the file will be uploaded and sent to the backend, but I'm unable to open it (further information below).
I don't get any error message when executing the first function, the upload process is successful, I just can't open the file afterwards.
onFileSelected: function (oEvent) {
  var oFile = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
  if (oFile) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var binaryContent = e.target.result;            
      var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
                            
      oModel.refreshSecurityToken(function (data, response) {
        var sToken = response.headers['x-csrf-token'];
        var sObjectKey = "Placeholder";
        var sObjectType = "BUS2081";
        var sFileName = oFile.name;
        var sSlug = btoa(sFileName);
        var sContentType = oFile.type;
                
        // Binary content as payload
        var oPayload = binaryContent;
                
        oModel.create("/OriginalContentSet", oPayload, {
          headers: {
            "x-csrf-token": sToken,
            "Slug": sSlug,
            "Objectkey": sObjectKey,
            "Objecttype": sObjectType,
          },
          success: function (data) {
            MessageToast.show("Success");
          },
          error: function (oError) {
            MessageToast.show("Error");
          }
        });
      }.bind(this), function () {
        MessageToast.show("Error with the CSRF Token");
      });
    }.bind(this);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(oFile); // Read file as binary ArrayBuffer (no Base64 encoding)
  } else {
    MessageToast.show("No file selected");
  }
}

I am 100% sure, that the variables like Slug, Contenttype, token etc. are correct, because I´ve replaced some variables with a Placeholder, but that doesn't matter, I just did this for this question because of privacy reasons.
I also have another method, that works perfectly fine, but in that method, I've used Ajax instead of oModel.create. Now I want to do the same, but with oModel.create, but it doesn't work. The file is uploaded correctly, but when trying to open it tells me that this file can't be opened and that "It may be damaged or in a format that Preview does not recognize." ...
I don't get an error during the upload process (sometimes I get "no handler for data", but I only got that when trying out different solutions...with the provided code I don't get any error).
I want the file to be attached to the invoice with the provided Objectkey, which works with both methods, but only the Ajax method also allows me to open the file after uploading it.
Here's the working method with Ajax as comparison:
onFileSelected: function (oEvent) {
  var oFile = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
  if (oFile) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var binaryContent = e.target.result;            
      var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
                            
      oModel.refreshSecurityToken(function (data, response) {
        var sToken = response.headers['x-csrf-token'];
        var sObjectKey = "Placeholder";
        var sObjectType = "BUS2081";
        var sFileName = oFile.name;
        var sSlug = btoa(sFileName);
        var sContentType = oFile.type;
                
        $.ajax({
          url: "placeholder/OriginalContentSet",
          type: "POST",
          data: binaryContent,
          processData: false, 
          contentType: sContentType,
          headers: {
            "x-csrf-token": sToken,
            "Slug": sSlug,
            "Objectkey": sObjectKey,
            "Objecttype": sObjectType
          },
          success: function (data) {
            MessageToast.show("Success");
          },
          error: function (oError) {
            MessageToast.show("Error");
          }
        });
      }.bind(this), function () {
        MessageToast.show("Error.");
      });
    }.bind(this);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(oFile); // Read file as binary ArrayBuffer (no Base64 encoding)
  } else {
    MessageToast.show("No file selected");
  }
}

I've tried changing the code a little bit, like creating a payload object with also the filename and content type in it instead of just saving the binary content into the payload variable, as well as moving variables from the payload object inside the header and the other way round, but the result is always the same.

Can you put a breakpoint in the backend and check how the uploaded content differs? Please update your post and add the results. You also didn't specify the content type in your non-Ajax request, maybe manually add this to the headers.

If you are using Odata v4 then oModel.create would not work. Instead use .bindItems()

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
